# Mean of Empirical Auto-Covariance

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Chris Chatfield's "The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction" 6th ed, gives the mean of the empirical auto-covariance as:

E(r_k)=-1/N

where E is the expectation
r_k is the empirical auto-covariance
N is the number of observations

1.) Can someone point me to a reference (ideally online) that derives this result?

2.) Even on an intuitive level where does the -1 come from.

Thanks

Baz